# Modal windows not masking properly in ExtJs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, modal-dialog, extjs4

I create a modal window like below:

```
var window = new Ext.Window({
  title: 'My Window'
  .....
  renderTo: 'panel.getEl()'
  modal: true
});
window.show();
```

As I am using the `renderTo` config property I would expect that ONLY the panel be masked. As was the case with my apps developed in ExtJs3.
However this does not seem to be the case in ExtJs4, as the whole document body is being masked.
Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this seems to be a bug with Ext JS 4, and I have logged it in our internal Sencha bug tracker for the next release.

In the future, it is best to post on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/) as you will get a quicker response.